Torch Installation to support YOLO
I'm following the instructions at https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

When I run the following command to test the installation
import torch
x = torch.rand(5, 3)
print(x)
I receive the following error, could I ask for assistance with the missing dependency? I'm on Windows 11. My understanding is since I don't have an NVIDIA CPU, moreover UHD Graphics 620 that I need to install the CPU only version

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
   File
"C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\torch_init_.py",
line 141, in 
raise err OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading
"C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll"
or one of its dependencies.

